# Define custom gmake function equivalent to multiple piped functions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to define a function that would to the work of `$(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(basename $(ARG1)))`

something like;

```
define getobj
    $(1): $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(basename $(1)))
endef
```

the context I'm trying to improve is:

```
OBJDIR = objects
TESTHNF_CPPS = testhnf.cpp timings.cpp LongModular.cpp VeryLong.cpp VeryLongModular.cpp squfof.cpp
TESTHNF_CS = mt19937int.c lip.c
TESTHNF_OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(basename $(TESTHNF_CPPS) $(TESTHNF_CS)))
TESTHNF_OBJS2 = $(getobj $(TESTHNF_CPPS) $(TESTHNF_CS))
```

Here, `$(TESTHNF_OBJS2)` remains empty. How should I write the function ?

Comment: Aside from Renaud's as always excellent answer you may want to look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) for a collection of GNUmake  functions for build configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getobj` macro looks like you want to declare a rule (`target: prerequisites`). But the use you try to make of it looks like you try to assign the result of its expansion to a variable, which does not really make sense.

So, let's ignore the rule look and concentrate on your goal (as far as I understand it): define a macro that gets the `basename` of each word it is passed and substitutes it for `$(OBJDIR)/<basename>.o`. You were almost there:

```
getobj = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(basename $(1)))
```

should make it, where `$(1)` is the macro's parameter, a list of space-separated words. And you call it with the [`call` make function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function):

```
TESTHNF_OBJS2 = $(call getobj,$(TESTHNF_CPPS) $(TESTHNF_CS))
```

The `call` make function substitutes `$(1)` for the `$(TESTHNF_CPPS) $(TESTHNF_CS)` parameter in the definition of `getobj` and returns the result. In your case it is equivalent to:

```
TESTHNF_OBJS2 = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(basename $(TESTHNF_CPPS) $(TESTHNF_CS)))
```

When `TESTHNF_OBJS2` will be expanded the result will be:

```
objects/testhnf.o objects/timings.o ... objects/lip.o
```

Back to the rule look. If what  you want instead is instantiate a make rule:

```
<basename>: $(OBJDIR)/<basename>.o
```

for each `<basename>` in your list, plus define a `TESTHNF_OBJS` variable listing all corresponding object files, what you can use is a combination of [`foreach`, `eval` and `call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function). But things are a bit more tricky because make expands the `eval` parameter once, instantiates the result as a make construct and expands it once more when parsing it as any regular make constructs. Double expansion must thus sometimes be escaped by doubling `$` signs; this is not your case but it is better to keep this in mind when using such things.

```
OBJDIR = objects
TESTHNF_CPPS = testhnf.cpp timings.cpp LongModular.cpp VeryLong.cpp VeryLongModular.cpp squfof.cpp
TESTHNF_CS = mt19937int.c lip.c
TESTHNF_OBJS :=

# $(1): basename of one source file
define getobj
    $(1): $(OBJDIR)/$(1).o

    TESTHNF_OBJS += $(OBJDIR)/$(1).o
endef
$(foreach b,$(basename $(TESTHNF_CPPS) $(TESTHNF_CS)),$(eval $(call $(b))))

clean:
    rm -f $(TESTHNF_OBJS)
```

As all this is rather complicated, and the benefits are quite low, it is probably better to stick with simpler constructs, easier to understand and maintain:

```
OBJDIR       := objects
TESTHNF_CPPS := testhnf.cpp timings.cpp LongModular.cpp VeryLong.cpp VeryLongModular.cpp squfof.cpp
TESTHNF_CS   := mt19937int.c lip.c
BASENAMES    := $(basename $(TESTHNF_CPPS) $(TESTHNF_CS))
TESTHNF_OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(BASENAMES)))

$(BASENAMES): %: $(OBJDIR)/%.o

clean:
    rm -f $(TESTHNF_OBJS)
```

The rule is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).